tailwind responsive design not working with prefix enabled
When using prefix:"tw-" in tailwind.config.js hidden with breakpoint not working.
Using : https://play.tailwindcss.com/
<div class="tw-md:hidden">hello</div>

div does not get hidden

config

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  prefix:"tw-"
}


Does this answer your question? Tailwind CSS group-hover not working with custom prefix

As per the documentation:

It’s important to understand that this prefix is added after any variant modifiers. That means that classes with responsive or state modifiers like sm: or hover: will still have the responsive or state modifier first, with your custom prefix appearing after the colon:
<div class="tw-text-lg md:tw-text-xl tw-bg-red-500 hover:tw-bg-blue-500">
  <!-- -->
</div>


So for your situation, it would be md:tw-hidden:


tailwind.config = { prefix: 'tw-' }
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.4"></script>

<div class="md:tw-hidden">hello</div>



